# Accessing property in a staticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use a property of a resource defined in xaml like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <map:TileLayer x:Key="OpenStreetMap" SourceName="OpenStreetMap"
                   Description="Maps © [OpenStreetMap Contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)"
                   TileSource="http://{c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                   MaxZoomLevel="14"/>
```

and then use the *Description* property to set *Text* of a TextBlock.
I have tried this but it does not work.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource OpenStreetMap.Description}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource OpenStreetMap.Description}"/>
```

How can I access the property in a resource defined in xaml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource OpenStreetMap}, Path=Description}"/>
```

Or shorter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, Source={StaticResource OpenStreetMap}}"/>
```

---

Note that the `Description` property contains markdown text. You could use the [`HyperlinkText`](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MapControl/HyperlinkText.cs) helper class like this:

```
<TextBlock map:HyperlinkText.InlinesSource="{Binding Description,
                                             Source={StaticResource OpenStreetMap}}"/>
```